# Is there a built in library of syntax in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I was wondering if there was any way of pulling up a list of functions/symbols and their descriptions? I've tried `help()`, but that only shows a list of symbols, and only shows their descriptions if you know which one you're looking for. I'm trying to find a way of figuring out which function/symbol to use to solve a problem without the help of a browser.

Comment: Did you try [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: You'd still be browsing locally...

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969093/how-to-search-help-using-python-console)?

Comment: Also, if we had a way of knowing what to write next, our programs would write themselves.

Comment: if you want to find an automated way to choose the appropriate library without browsing; it is not possible neither today nor in near future.

Comment: At first I should say that it hasn't any problem to use a browser for helping. This is inevitable. All  the programmer use it in any level. Then you can use Python Docs in help menu of IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

The Python standard library is *massive*. You're going to have a bad time of it without the [Python docs site](https://docs.python.org/3/). Note that there is a [download link](https://docs.python.org/3/download.html) so that you can have it locally; that can satisfy your "without a browser" problem, if you use the plain text version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this page as reference :

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Or try `pydoc` or `help()` or `dir()`.

For example in console search anything after help command like this :

```
>>> help(max)

Help on built-in function max in module __builtin__:

max(...)
    max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
    max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value

    With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
    With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
(END)
```

Or like this for available modules:

```
pydoc -k <keyword>
    Search for a keyword in the synopsis lines of all available modules.
```

for example :

```
pydoc -k doc

DocXMLRPCServer - Self documenting XML-RPC Server.
doctest - Module doctest -- a framework for running examples in docstrings.
email.mime.application - Class representing application/* type MIME documents.
email.mime.audio - Class representing audio/* type MIME documents.
email.mime.image - Class representing image/* type MIME documents.
email.mime.message - Class representing message/* MIME documents.
email.mime.text - Class representing text/* type MIME documents.
markupbase - Shared support for scanning document type declarations in HTML and XHTML.
pydoc - Generate Python documentation in HTML or text for interactive use.
pydoc_data 
pydoc_data.topics 
xml.dom - W3C Document Object Model implementation for Python.
setuptools.command.upload_docs - upload_docs
```

Have a good time .